# fail-safe cleanup (collections) warning after committing transaction with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhprof

When looking in NHProfiler I get following warning after committing my transaction:

fail-safe cleanup (collections) : NHibernate.Engine.Loading.CollectionLoadContext

I have absolutely no idea what this could be or how I can solve this. Can somebody help me?

Thanks,
Jelle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an [NHibernate bug](http://groups.google.com/group/nhprof/browse_thread/thread/d2e3d6fc52b179f1) that you can ignore. I haven't noticed it since I upgraded NHIbernate to 2.1.2.GA.